# Does onkeydown type of event make sense in a server side?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, events

In case of C#, when we code a keydown event which usually works in server side, what happend?
Can PHP do that? or should work only in javascript which is client side?
Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: depends on what you want to do in the event. most of the time the code will do client-side things (css, javascript effects, etc), therefore no serverside intervention is required.

Comment: you should say it as an awnser, thanks. And which case should keydown events be catched in server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a web application, the user interacts with the web application through a browser client, which is able to execute Javascript on the client, not the server. Any client events will be handled in Javascript. PHP is executed solely on the server, and therefore has no idea when client events occur unless you write Javascript code to send these events to the server using AJAX

Comment: its translated into javascript by C#, the javascript data is then send to the client as part of the response, the client's browser then compiles the javascript and executes it client side, there is not really much else to it,

Comment: In ASP.NET, the difference between client/server is, in many cases, abstracted away from the programmer, so the language itself handles this for you, and generates Javascript code for the client during compilation (this is how GWT works with Java). Since you are writing Javascript directly, you get to deal with all the hairy details ;-) I strongly agree with @luca in recommending jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Both PHP and C# (behind a web server) are server side language, so they do not handle any event raised in the client side.

So you should handle the event with JavaScript (i suggest you to take a look at jQuery). With JavaScript, if you need a server interaction, you can send an Ajax request to your server and eventually return some values to the client side.